# Can I use an image instead of a title in an Apple Watch app?

Tags: fullscreen, watchkit

How can I put an icon in the top left label and make fullscreen? Apple allocates some space on top for the digital clock and back label. I would like to customize it, but I can't find anything in the SDK to enable this.

Comment: not possible in first cut, may come later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top strip of the Watch screen is reserved for displaying the page title, or occasionally links such as "Cancel" by default for modal views, and the clock. It is not possible to hide this.

It is possible to set an empty title for a page. Some settings will alsoplace a background image behind this text (if you set the mode to 'Aspect Fill', at least in the current Xcode 6.2 beta 3). However, the portion of the image at the top of the screen is simply occluded by a black strip, so this does not achieve what you want.

Additionally, Apple have specifically recommended against displaying logos on the Apple Watch screen, with the rationale that the screen is too small to display for the user anything but actual content.

To set the Global tint:

1. Select the Interface Controller itself in Interface Builder by clicking on the Yellow circle at the top of the view of the screen.
2. Press Cmd-Opt-1 to display the File Inspector section of the Utilites on the right hand side.
3. Set the 'Global Tint' option in the section 'Interface Builder Document', as per the screenshot.

[image: Setting global tint in a WatchKit App]

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in the first cut but I think it will come later.

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually a back label. The text in the top left of the Watch screen is the title of the current WKInterfaceController. You can change it by using `-[WKInterfaceTitle setTitle:]`, but you are limited to content that is expressible in an `NSString` (so no `UIImages`).

Comment: Is there a  way to change color or size of font for this string?

Comment: @vitalii The color is determined by the tint color of your application. The size and font are determined by the OS and are not customizable.

Comment: Great. since there is no application class for watch, how do we get and set Tint color?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to customise the status bar in watchOS 4.

1. Select your interface controller in the storyboard
2. Open the attributes inspector
3. Check the Full Screen checkbox

After doing this you can add your custom image to the left of the statusbar.

Comment: Full screen in watchOS 4 only applies to SpriteKit and SceneKit scenes. Other interface elements still cannot be placed in the title area.